# Preventing data to be entered on browser refresh as well as on browser start

Tags: php, mysql

when we open registration webpage, an empty data gets inserted into database as well as on browser refresh. 
we have tried:

```
header("Location: addcandidate.php");
exit(0);
```

we have tried to put this code after all $_POST values and also at beginning of page.
we are getting error as:`Cannot modify header information - headers already sent

```
        $addcandidate1=$_POST['candi_a_fname'];
        $addcandidate2=$_POST['candi_a_lname'];`
        header("Location: addcandidate.php");
        exit(0);

        mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die(mysql_error());
        echo "connected"; 

        mysql_select_db('talent') or die(mysql_error());
        echo "database selected"; 

        $error = NULL;
        if (!$error) 
        {
            mysql_query("insert into candidate(cand_fname,cand_lname) values ('$addcandidate1','$addcandidate2')") or die(mysql_error());

            echo 'alert("Your Data Has Been Successfully Inserted ! Thank    You")';

        }
```

Comment: post your code please

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to fix "Headers already sent" error in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php)

Comment: The thing you are looking for is to catch your form submit..

Comment: @Sean..looks good . Hope i get the solution. I will let You know after implementing it. Thank You

Comment: @Naruto..I have problem with data entered on browser refresh or on visit of that webpage..not on form submit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add :

```
if($_POST['submit']) {
//your code
}
```

to run it only when the form has been submit.
You should also stop using mysql_ methods, and go for PDO to use prepared statement.

Comment: Is it necessary to use PDO statements because I am using mysqli.

Comment: Well, you are using mysql methods : "mysql_query", "mysql_connect",...
and this is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0

Comment: @xNeyte..this is try code...if successfull. i am implementing with mysqli..:)

Comment: thank you guys. We have done with the solution. Just removed the header location part and used id of the submit button. It working for us. Thank you all again.